# How can I prevent styles-l.css loading for mobile only?

Tags: magento2, css, optimization, styles

I'm trying to clean up some of our over stuffed css and js. Chrome inspector shows that styles-l.css is 100% unused for mobile and is used a little for desktop. I used 'remove' in the default_head_blocks.xml for the mobile theme and achieved the results I hoped for, no longer loaded for mobile and desktop unaffected.

It later crossed my mind that I hadn't tested at tablet resolution. It appears tablet resolution uses the mobile theme but also uses some styles from styles-l.css. It looked a mess on ipad. This was quite disappointing. Can anyone suggest a method of applying styles-l.css to desktop AND tablet but not to mobile please?

If anyone is kind enough to reply, please bear in mind that I'm not a programmer or developer, admin is the safe limit of my knowledge. I dabble in configuration and installation but continue to be baffled by Magento 2 styles pre processing and which files need to be changed to alter styles prior to deployment.
Thanks..